# always return false while judge file existence in perl

Tags: perl, io

following example works perfectly for me

```
if(-e "/tmp/test.txt"){  
  print "the file exists\n";

}else{
  print "no file \n";
}
```

but if I make changes to get file dynamically it will not work and always rerun false

```
@files=();
$target="*";
$subdir="Y";
$dir="/tmp/";

find ( \&file_wanted, $dir);

foreach $file (@files ){

    if(-e $file){  
      print "the file exists\n";

    }else{
      print "no file \n";
    }
}
```

function for  file_wanted attached below

```
sub file_wanted {

    ##########################################################
    #  $_ contains the current filename within the directory
    #  $File::Find::dir contains the current directory name
    #  $File::Find::name contains $File::Find::dir/$_
    #####################################################

    # use regular expression

    #if ( ( $target ne '*' ) &&  !( $_ =~ /$target/ )) { 
    #   return;     
    #}
    if( $target eq '*'){
       if ( $subdir eq 'Y' ) {  
        #recursive subdirectory search
        push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"  if -f; 
       } else  {            
        push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"  if -f && $File::Find::dir eq $dir ;
       }
    }else{
    if ( $subdir eq 'Y' ) {  
    #recursive subdirectory search
        push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"  if -f && $_  =~ /$target/; 
       } else  {            
        push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"  if -f && $File::Find::dir eq $dir && $_  =~ /$target/ ;
       }
   }
}
```

can anyone advise how this happening and thanks in advance

Comment: You are appending `\n` at last with this `$File::Find::name\n`  remove it and it will work.

Comment: but I need remove all the files under the path recursively. if remove the \n, all these files will be messed up. so I think I should remove the \n in the for loop I think

Comment: I am not saying you to remove any files, I am just saying change `push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"` to `push @files, "$File::Find::name"`

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to mix 'glob' style `*` patterns with regex matches. It's a road to future confusion.

Comment: @AruneshSingh thanks Singh. I imported function chomp. and it works good now.

Comment: @Sobrique ....legacy system.. so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You treat the elements of `@files` as paths, but they aren't. The elements of `@files` are paths concatenated with linefeeds.

Change

```
push @files, "$File::Find::name\n"
```

to

```
push @files, $File::Find::name
```

---

By the way, using `-e` that way isn't quite correct. When an error occurs, the file is reported as being non-existent even if it exists. If you wanted to handle errors, you could use the following:

```
if (-e $qfn) {
   # File exists
   ...
}
elsif ($!{ENOENT}) {
   # File doesn't exist
   ...
}
else {
   # Could not determine if the file exists or not. Error in $!
   ...
}
```